# <input type="text" /> with line wrap

Tags: jquery, input, textarea, word-wrap

I would love to display text inputs, but they should break if the text is too long. But the user should not be able to insert new lines by himself The reason for that is that I always want to have it's whole value visible.

I think that there is no solution with CSS, which would be best, so I decided to replace all input elements with textarea elements and automatically adjust it's height. To prevent multiple lines I simply replace them.

I did it with this code, but especially the part where I grab all the input's attributes to convey them to the texarea seems awkward to me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        var attrs = { rows: 1 }, defaults = ['name', 'id', 'title', 'value', 'class', 'style', 'disabled', 'readonly', 'accesskey'];
        for(var i in defaults){
            if($(this).is(':[' + defaults[i] + ']')){
                attrs[defaults[i]] = $(this).attr(defaults[i]);
            }
        }
        attrs["class"] = (attrs["class"] || "") + " text-input";
        $(this).replaceWith($('<textarea />', attrs).change(function(){
            $(this).val(function(i, v){
                return v.replace(/\n/g, " ");
            }).css("height", $(this).attr("scrollHeight"));
        }));
    });
});
```

Do you know any improvements?

Comment: Do you not have access to the backend code?  I would replace input elements with textareas on the backend.

Comment: Yes, I do, but to me it seems better to replace them client side. Because if someone has javascript disabled he then would know that he is not expected to type line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use a `<textarea>` and add js w/ jQuery to return false if a keypress was 'enter'. I think it's a bit lighter weight. E.g.

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(evt){
  if (evt.keyCode == 13) { return false; }
});
```

Admittedly, it's not fool-proof, but you can add code to scrub the contents of the textarea when its value changes.

Comment: What a brilliant answer, thank you very much! This seems more elegant to me. It sadly still does not fix the way how I create the the textarea's attributes. You got an advice for that too? (:

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you're doing with the attrs and defaults. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Yes of course! I want the textarea to have all attributes of the input. So now I am iterating through a list of attribute names and "copy" it to my new textarea element if such an attribute exists. This does not seem very straight forward for me. It would be much better if I could catch all attributes at once.

Comment: Okay, I kind of thought so, but if you use my method, then you'll be creating <textarea>s instead of <input>s, so you can just add the attributes directly to them instead of stripping them from inputs. ...Or do you mean that right now you are physically changing your html code to put aforesaid swap into place? If so, js is not a great way to do it; I recommend using an html parser to create an node tree, altering elements of the tree, and then outputting the tree back to html. (This can be done with about 4-5 lines of code.) Are you familiar with other interpreted langs, like Python or Ruby?

Comment: If I get your answer right you're asking me to use <textarea>s directly instead of replacing <input>s. The inputs are created dynamically anyway so it would not be too much effort to change them into textarea tags. Of course this would be an easy way to save the trouble to create a new tag with the old one's attributes, but it seems a bit inaccurate to me, because if someone has javascript disabled he then would have a multi-line input field which would be wrong: The user is not expected to use multiple lines, he only should be able to see all the contend, no matter how long it is. :-)